# Epson WF-4630 print output too light

Tags: drivers, printing

When I print from my Ubuntu computer (lenovo G580) the output looks faded to the point of almost being unreadable. All colors, black and greyscale are too light.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

Today, I installed the latest EPSON driver for the printer (epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.4.5-1lsb3.2_i386.deb) from the corporate website. I deleted, then re-installed my printer, cycled the printer power, then printed the test page. No improvement.

When I print from my Windows 7 computer, the output is as expected (that is, good color and black and greyscale depths).

I've looked for controls to change the density of the printing, but can find none.

Thanks for any help that can be offered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Under the printer properties, try changing the media type to "plain papers-Standard-Vivid".
For me, changing it in the printer properties from the System Settings doesn't seem to change the default in apps like the PDF viewer. I need to set it each time I print.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem with Epson WF-7620 and Ubuntu 16.04. Changing **Media type** under printer properties to [user3014416's suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/590056/527764) only partly helped, but for me changing it to **plain papers-High** resulted in good printing quality.